# Are there any methods so that I can search for all users who earned the particular hat?

Tags: discussion, data-explorer, winter-bash

Are there any methods so that I can search for all users who earned the particular hat(s)?

Is Data Explorer helpful for doing those by writing some new queries?

Answer (score 3):

Searchable [leaderboard](http://winterbash2013.stackexchange.com/leaderboard/math.stackexchange.com) is available; however the search is by user name, not by hat name.

> I don't think this is something we could realistically put in the data explorer. It would be a bit of a challenge because the event is very short-lived, and we'd have to do some interesting hackery to get the data into data explorer itself (creating the dump, dealing with the schema, etc).
>
> However, I'll see if we can include some interesting data (most popular, least popular, most common, rarest, etc) when we wrap the event up in January.

-- [Tiny Tim ♦ aka Tim Post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/212009)